# Do I need the definite article 'The' before 'construction'?

Tags: definite-articles, zero-article

Recently I had a conversation with a colleague and ran into a problem I can't stop thinking about. I was talking about the new campus of my university and said 'construction was started in 2012'. Is it correct not to use the definite article in this sentence? By 'construction' I mean a set of different construction activities. At the same time it could have meant the construction process of that specific building we both were aware of. What is the difference?

Comment: The article is optional although it depends on the wider context. "The construction" would specify that the topic was the specific construction of the campus, but you can also use "construction" to refer generally to any building works. (Compare "Ants ate my picnic" - some ants, and "The ants ate my picnic" - specific ants.) I'm pretty sure there have been a lot of similar questions but it can be hard to search for "the".

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's now much clearer.

Comment: To me, adding an article before "construction" makes it refer to the thing that was constructed, not the process of constructing.

Comment: E.g. "The construction was built in 2010." versus "Construction of the building took place in 2010."

Answer (score 0):

From a comment by StuartF:

> The article is optional although it depends on the wider context. "The construction" would specify that the topic was the specific construction of the campus, but you can also use "construction" to refer generally to any building works. (Compare "Ants ate my picnic" - some ants, and "The ants ate my picnic" - specific ants.) I'm pretty sure there have been a lot of similar questions but it can be hard to search for "the".